Minimum spanning polyhedron
I'm not sure if the subject line "Minimum spanning polyhedron" is the correct verbiage.
I am interested in determining the coordinates of a k points (model parameter) that enclose a series of data points and whether such an algorithm exists.
Suppose the case where $k=4$. The model would likely return a four points, the corners of a square or rhombus, that enclose all data points (assuming data has two dimensions.)
The goal of the algorithm would be to minimize the polyhedron's area while enclosing all data points.
I'm not certain how to optimize such an algorithm. My top concern is that a given point is either enclosed (or not), which is binary. So the "loss function" would likely not be differentiable, limiting relevance of algorithms like gradient descent. (However if minor violations are tolerated GD might be feasible; though this doesn't fully address the question.)
My questions are

Is this a known problem with an established solution?
If yes, please link resource. If not, what are some concerns you'd have when articulating a loss function?

Thank you!

This is not completely clear. Maybe what you want is convex hull. Look that up.

I agree with @EthanBolker that what you want is probably the convex hull. I'll add that in order to think algorithmically, you'll need to ask yourself: how is this polytope represented? There are typically two representations: vertex representations and hyperplane representations. The one you want depends on your task.

Instead of the vertices of a square, a rectangle or a rhombus you could consider a general minimal area bounding quadrilateral as in  this question and its answer.

@EthanBolker - Convex Hull is exactly what I am looking for! This term was not in my vocabulary when I posted this question. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction :)

Apparently, there are a lot of algorithms for Convex Hull  https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convex-hull-algorithm/

@jbuddy_13 You're welcome. You can delete the question, or ask me to post my comment as an answer. One way or the other so the question does not remain on the open queue.

@EthanBolker I'm happy to award the answer points if you would like to post as an answer

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11602259/find-the-smallest-containing-convex-polygon-with-a-given-number-of-points

What you want is the convex hull. There are many known algorithms for computing it. Which work  for you depends on the way your data are organized.

In the question, there is a model parameter $k$ which is the maximum number of points for the bounding shape; and the problem is to minimise that shape's area subject to the constraint that it bounds the points. So it is not simply the convex hull.

@kaya3 The comment I turned into an answer at the OP's request only suggested that the convex hull might be what was needed. I don't claim I have the full answer to what the OP needs.
